# Сортированный Vector, сортированный ArrayList

Tags: java, vector, коллекции, arraylist

Здравствуйте. В гугле не нашел почти никакой информации по этому поводу.

Скажите, *за какое время можно найти элемент по его значению в Vector'e и ArrayList'e?* 
Чем объясняется время поиска? Я почему-то думаю, что за О(n), т.к. все равно придется пробегаться по всем элементам, пока не найдем тот, который нужен. 
Но, с другой стороны, почему-то мне кажется, что за О(log(n))

Заранее спасибо

Comment: в отсортированном можно за log(n) с помощью бинарного поиска

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если массив не отсортирован, то сложность алгоритма поиска, очевидно, `O(N)`, поскольку мы не можем делать выводы о значениях соседних элементов на основании значения выбранного элемента.

В случае отсортированного массива, можно воспользоваться [бинарным поиском](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA), сокращая сложность до `O(log(N))`.

Касаемо различий между поиском в `ArrayList` и `Vector` - разницы практически не будет, поскольку каждый из этих контейнеров предоставляет доступ к элементу по индексу, что критически важно для бинарного поиска.